# CodeIgniter base_url leads to page not found

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter, and I'm new at it, as I'm in web development.
I'm having a problem with the `base_url` from CI: it leads to `404 Page not found`.

Here is the referrence for the page:

```
<li><a href="<?=base_url('Usual/novo_usual')?>">Cadastrar</a></li>
```

The controller's function:

```
function novo_usual(){
    $this->load->view('html-header');
    $this->load->view('html-footer');
    $this->load->view('cadastro_usual');
}
```

My controller's name file starts in capital, like Usual.php, and it extends `CI_Controller`.

My altoloado.php:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','html','form','funcoes');
```

My routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Home';
```

Finally the .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You forgot to define a route for `Usual/novo_usual`

Comment: Have u tried to use only base_url(); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve it.
Turns out that my project's name starts with 'G', and in my url I was calling it with 'g'.
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

See \application\config\config.php

$config['base_url'] = '';

write to this your site url.

for example

$config['base_url'] = 'http://test.com/';

and now if you use base_url('Usual/novo_usual') this is equal http://test.com/Usual/novo_usual

Comment: I've set this '$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/geoportal/';' , but still not working.

Comment: for control do this
<li><a href="localhost/geoportal/Usual/novo_usua">Cadastrar</a></li>
save and go link
after say problem is it or all good. May be problem with not base_url

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set site url then first of set its

```
 //Site URL Path : application\config\config.php

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/site_name';
```

Then add this :

```
<?php 

  echo site_url('Usual/novo_usual');

//OR

 echo base_url('Usual/novo_usual'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to set your folder path in

\application\config\config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

for example

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/folder/';
```